# Table internal borders not showing

Tags: html, css

I'm using the CSS class shown below to format a table. The table shows only an outside border, not internal borders.

There are no other styling options set, just the `<table class="my-table">`.

What have I missed / done wrong, please?

```css
table.my-table {
        border: solid thin;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0px;
        border-color: black;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    
            table.my-table tbody th {
                background: rgb(28, 58, 112);
                background: rgba(28, 58, 112, 1);
                color: rgb(255,255,255);
                color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
            }
    
            table.my-table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
                background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
            }
    
            table.my-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
                background: rgb(239, 239, 239);
                background: rgba(239, 239, 239, .8);
            }
    
            table.my-table tbody td {
                background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
                color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
            }
```

```html
<table class="my-table">
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What have I missed / done wrong, please?

You've only set a border on the table.

The CSS `border` property is not equivalent to the obsolete `border` attribute.

If you want to set borders on the cells, then you have to write a selector which targets those cells and set the `border` on them.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS border properties allow you to specify the style, width, and color of an element's border. In your code you set the style for the table, not for the individual cells in the table. 
To fix this simple add:

```
table.my-table tbody td {
            border: solid thin;
```